# Wants to deploy my flutter app instead of an old cordova app, without my users logout

Tags: flutter, cordova, migration, storage, upgrade

My old cordova app, is saving local data with native-storage.
My new flutter app is using shared preferances.
Is there any way to read the cordova local data after the user upgrade ?

Answer (score 0):

> saving local data with native-storage

if you mean use shared preference, then try get your data in flutter with same key,

but if you use local db such as SQLite, you have to read your sqlite db with your flutter app.